# Access Jenkins running in Private subnet AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have Jenkins running on a single ec2 instance which resides in private subnet in a VPC. How can I access the jenkins apps from my local host's browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Private subnets are meant to be just that, private. You do have a couple of options.

1) Add a public facing load balancer in front of it

2) Create another EC2 instance that has access to Jenkins and RDP into it and use Jenkins from there

3) Create an EC2 instance with something like openVPN on it and VPN into the network and create routes that allow you to then access Jenkins from there.

4) Move Jenkins to a public subnet. You can restrict HTTP access using security groups so that only your IP address (or subnet) can access it.